# C++ Posição na tela fica estranha quando tento converter da função GetCursorPos to SendInputs

Tags: c++, winapi

Utilizei a função `GetCursorPos` para pegar umas posições na tela que eu gostaria que o mouse fosse capaz de clicar para realizar uma tarefa para mim e automatizar o serviço.

Testei selecionar essas posições com o `SetCursorPos` e funcionou, entretanto o programa que uso necessita ser fullscreen e a função `SetCursorPos` não funciona, assim utilizei a função `SendInput` porém as mesmas coordenadas parecem diferentes.

Segue o código da parte do `SendInput`:

```
inline bool mouse_move(int x, int y)
{
    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    input.mi.mouseData = 0;
    input.mi.time = 0;
    input.mi.dx = (x + 1) * (65535 / GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN));//x being coord in pixels
    input.mi.dy = (y + 1) * (65535 / GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));//y being coord in pixels
    input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
    return true;
}
```

Segue a função que adquiri as posições na tela.

```
POINT P;
GetCursorPos(&P);
```

Claramente isso necessita algum tipo de conversão das coordenadas mas não consigo realizar tal coisa.

Comment: "entretanto o programa que uso necessita ser fullscreen e a função SetCursorPos não funciona " Deu algum erro ? não deu os valores que pretendia ? O que aconteceu ?

Comment: Ele não move o mouse, simplesmente ignora a função, enquanto que o sendinput ele movimenta o mouse mas o posicionamento fica errado.